# Codeception not fill input

Tags: php, xpath, codeception, acceptance-testing

Im trying to change the value off an input field with the method fillField:
Im using XPath to get the input field.

`$I->fillField('//*[@id="123"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/input', '10');`

and the input tag looks like:

`<input type="text" name="1" alt="number" value="11">`

The test doesnt fill the input.
Im getting this exception when im trying to test, if the input tag was filled:

`9. $I->see("10","input")
 8. $I->fillField("//*[@id="123"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/input","10")`

The test failed at Position 9.

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing? Does it do something, just not what you expect? Please add some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

`see()` checks HTML of the page, `fillField()` does not update it,

If you want to see if fillField is working, submit the form after filling the field and run Codeception with `-vvv` flag and find `[Parameters]` in the output.